# Search after a match once per line

Tags: linux, string, perl, search

I'm trying to create a script to get all the Apache response after specific word "statusDescription", but I have a problem that I got the output duplicated for some rows as matched word or response maybe written 2 times @ the same line

Sample of log "1 line":

`GET/en?status=1&newMainBalance=5486&serviceAmount=700&ExternalTrxId=asdf&PgTrxId=tfpsadf&amount=0&statusDescription=Failed&customerCode=1.1&newDedicatedBalance=0&secureHash=56a7sdyf&paidAmount=1000&responseMsg=%a1%a1%A1(PG_ID)&language=enHTTP/1.1"200186243**1/1210669**1"-""-""-""https://example.com.eg?statusDescription=Failed&externalTrxId=123&status=203&secureHash=asdf&pgTrxId=asdf`

i tried the below command to get any match between "statusDescription" and "&"

```
cat test.txt  | perl -nle'print $1 while /statusDescription(.*?)\&/g'
cat test.txt  | perl -nle'print $1 while /statusDescription(.*?)\&/g'
```

output:

> =Failed
>   =Failed

i except the result to be 1 line only like

> =Failed

or

> =Failed=Failed

Comment: Try sed: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/

Comment: Also watch the [useless use of `cat`](/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `-l` option without a value. To quote from [perlrun](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html):

> If octnum is omitted, sets `$\` to the current value of `$/`

which by default is `\n`. Hence every print will automatically get a `\n` appended.

```perl
$  echo 'Match=once& should only Match=twice& once' | perl -nle 'print "MATCH ->$1<-" while /Match(.*?)&/g'
MATCH ->=once<-
MATCH ->=twice<-

# the same without -l
$ echo 'Match=once& should only Match=twice& once' | perl -ne 'print "MATCH ->$1<-" while /Match(.*?)&/g'
MATCH ->=once<-MATCH ->=twice<-

# if your post-processing requires matches from different lines to appear
# on separate lines then append a conditional print "\n" at the end
$ echo 'Match=once& should only Match=twice& once' | perl -ne 'print "MATCH ->$1<-" while /Match(.*?)&/g; print "\n" if $1'
MATCH ->=once<-MATCH ->=twice<-
$ echo 'nomatch=once& should only nomatch=twice& once' | perl -ne 'print "MATCH ->$1<-" while /Match(.*?)&/g; print "\n" if defined $1'
$
```

For `$/` (input record separator) and `$\` (output record separator) see also [perlvar](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).

Comment: thanks a lot for your support , can you please help me in 1 more thing. 
it worked with me , but i faced 1 more issue that it return null when Statusdescription is located at the end of line .

for example : GET/en?status=1&newMainBalance=5486&serviceAmount=700&ExternalTrxId=asdf&PgTrxId=tfpsadf&amount=0&statusDescription=Failed" so it doesn't match the criteria for "&" 

can i make it more generic , just match 1 word after "StatusDescription=" and before "&" or not

Comment: That's actually another question, but you could try to split lines on `&` and then match on the parts. E.g. `perl -ne 'foreach my $p (split(/&/)) { print "$1\n" if $p =~ /^statusDescription(=.*)/; }'`

Comment: but if i split the line on "&"  , it will duplicate the output in case i have 2 statusdescription on the same line (one before & and another one in end of the line) and i need to terminate after first match to get accurate result

thanks alot for your support in advance , you really helped me alot

Comment: OK, you only want to find and print the first match? Then this should do it `perl -ne 'foreach my $p (split(/&/)) { if ($p =~ /^statusDescription(=.*)/) { print "$1\n"; last } }'`

Comment: Hello Stefan Becker 
i faced a new issue that i found duplicates some time so i need to add a new match to filter with it so i need to get statusdescrition as before and add pgtrxid to be like that (pgTrxId=asdf&statusDescription=Failed) bearing in mind to ignore case sensitive for pgtrxid

Answer (score 2):

The `-l` is having the effect of printing a line feed after each `print`.

The following will print the value of the (first) `statusDescription` field of the requested URL (while ignoring the referrer URL). It will even correctly decode the value for you (if it contains escaped characters such as `+` or `%20`).

```
perl -MURI -MURI::QueryParam -nle'
   my ($request_url) = /^\S+\s+(\S+)/
      or next;
   $request_url = URI->new($request_url, "http");
   my $status = $request_url->query_param("statusDescription")
      or next;
   print $status;
' test.txt
```